# What do the values in trees of Random forest GEE mean?

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest, image-classification

I get these trees in GEE:

```
 trees: List (29 elements)    0: n= 116838
node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
* denotes terminal node
1) root 116838 31180 8 (0.010997 0.0066155 0.019316 0.013984 0.012195 0.016243 0.055491 0.011528 0.85363)
 2) B3_winter<=0.363000 17211 13821 6 (0.073113 0.044483 0.12770 0.091521 0.082520 0.10987 0.37613 0.049187 0.045470)
```

As i understand right in `(0.073113 0.044483 0.12770 0.091521 0.082520 0.10987 0.37613 0.049187 0.045470)` - rate of each classes if we apply this rule and equal 1 in sum;
In this expression `B3_winter<=0.363000 17211 13821 6` , 6 - number of class, what do these two values mean : `17211 13821` and what means `29 elements` if i number of trees = 100, and also all 29 elements begin from the same expression:

```
n= 116838
node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
* denotes terminal node
1) root 116838 31180 8 (0.010997 0.0066155 0.019316 0.013984 0.012195 0.016243 0.055491 0.011528 0.85363)
```

what does this expression mean?